# Emacs not indenting enum / enum class contents

Tags: indentation, c++, c, doom

I've got a small problem to do with Doom Emacs / Emacs. Enum contents are not indented at all...

Here's what I would like:

```cpp
enum class RandomEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
};
```

Here's what I get:

```cpp
enum class RandomEnum
{
A,
B,
C,
D
};
```

How can I go about fixing this? I'm sure that there a simple option I can put in my config? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't enough information to go off. Which major mode is this in? Can you reproduce the issue from `emacs -Q`? If not, can you recursively bisect your configuration to determine the source of the behaviour? Etc. If you discover a bug in a built-in mode, please report it to the Emacs bug tracker via `M-x report-emacs-bug RET`; if it's a bug in a third-party package, report it to their bug tracker / maintainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs [comes with some preconfigured C/C++ Styles](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Built_002din-Styles.html#Built_002din-Styles).
You can [change the indentation style of the current buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Custom-C-Indent.html) with `C-c .`

When you have chosen a style and only want to [temporary/test adjust a few offsets](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Customizing-C-and-C_002b_002b-indentation.html) `C-c C-o` helps. Emacs indentation styles can be modified very fine grained.

[You can also set a default style by changing the alist `c-default-style`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Choosing-a-Style.html)

---

Given the above information, the elisp code following will set the indentation style "stroustrup" as default style for c++ source code. Then it modifies this style to give the indentation for your example:

```
(defun change-c-style (c-style-name option-section add-options)
  "function to easily change a predefined indentation style."
  (let ((tmp (assoc option-section (assoc c-style-name c-style-alist))))
    (when tmp
      (setf (cdr tmp) (append (cdr tmp) add-options))))  )

(require 'cc-mode) ;; load up c++-mode environment
(push '(c++-mode . "stroustrup") c-default-style) ;; make "stroustrup" the default style for c++ files
(change-c-style "stroustrup" 'c-offsets-alist '((brace-list-open . 0) (brace-list-intro . ++))) ;; modify the "stroustrup" style with above defined function
```

Evaling above elisp code and then opening a c++-file will give you the wanted indentation by pressing `tab`

Above code is meant as a working example, because your question did not deliver enough information about your current environment.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked very nicely!